# Why is request-promise not returning the results to postman and angular 2's map?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, service, promise

We have an Angular 4 [service](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4) with a function like this:

```
callPostAPI() {

    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    let options = {}; //passing no options

      return this.http.post('http://localhost:9000/v1/api/testapi', options, {
          headers: headers
        })
        .map((response: Response) => {

          return response.json();
        })
        .catch((error: Response) => {
          return Observable.throw(error || 'server error');
        });
}
```

The [rp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) function is like this:

```
app.post("/v1/api/testapi", (req, res) => {

    rp({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',
      qs: {
        address: '66309'
      }
    })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res); //proper results received
        return res;
    }).catch(err => {
        return err;
    });
}
```

However, this is not returning any response when called either from [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/postman) or through Angular 4 service function.

The results are received and we can see them on the `console` as well. All this is working without headers.

> Why is `request-promise` not returning the results?

Comment: Try looking at the request headers

Comment: @MikeTung The results are received and we can see them on the console as well. All this is working without headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never handle the result of request promise on your server side. I'm assuming you are using express, try this:

```
app.post("/v1/api/testapi", (req, res, next) => {

    rp({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',
      qs: {
        address: '66309'
      }
    })
      .then(result => {
        console.log(res); //proper results received
        return res.status(200).json(result);
    }).catch(next);
}
```

Comment: Can you please educate me more on this please?

Comment: have a look at the docs, they are pretty good https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res

Comment: Status 200 is set by default, so you can just call `res.send(result)`. Also `return` statement is not required there.

Answer (score 0):

Use ***subscribe*** insted of ***then*** , i too had same issue but trying the above solved for me.

Comment: where shall I use subscribe? In node? `TypeError: rp(...).subscribe is not a function` and in angular 2 also. The problem is with `rp` it is not giving back the results

Comment: This seems to be due to CORS issue. Cross origin request are not accepted by the browser by default. U must specify them in the header separately.